# How do I create a trigger in a Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, migration

I’m trying to add some triggers to my PostgreSQL (v 9) db and I would like to create a Rails migration (using v 4.2.7) to satisfy this goal.  So I created a migration with this content

```
class CreateDeleteAddressTriggers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_address() RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
        $$BEGIN
          DELETE FROM public.addresses WHERE id = OLD.address_id;
      END;$$;

      CREATE TRIGGER remove_my_object_address
        AFTER DELETE ON public.my_objects FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()

      CREATE TRIGGER remove_user_address
        AFTER DELETE ON public.users FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()
    SQL
  end
end
```

Unfortunately when I run the “rake db:migrate” task, I get the following error

```
davea$ rake db:migrate
== 20160928184431 CreateDeleteAddressTriggers: migrating ======================
-- execute("      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_address() RETURNS trigger\n        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS\n        $$BEGIN\n          DELETE FROM public.addresses WHERE id =  OLD.address_id;\n      END;$$;\n\n      CREATE TRIGGER remove_my_object_address\n        AFTER DELETE ON public.my_objects FOR EACH ROW\n        EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()\n\n       CREATE TRIGGER remove_user_address\n        AFTER DELETE ON public.users FOR EACH ROW\n        EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()\n")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TRIGGER"
LINE 9:         EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()
                        ^
:       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION remove_address() RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
        $$BEGIN
          DELETE FROM public.addresses WHERE id = OLD.address_id;
      END;$$;

      CREATE TRIGGER remove_my_object_address
        AFTER DELETE ON public.my_objects FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()

      CREATE TRIGGER remove_user_address
        AFTER DELETE ON public.users FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE TRIGGER remove_address()
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:484:in `block in log'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:478:in `log'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
```

How can I correct my migration in order to run the triggers properly?

**Edit:** In response to the answer given, this was the error generated ...

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 11:       CREATE TRIGGER remove_user_address
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax in your SQL. You need `EXECUTE PROCEDURE`, not `EXECUTE TRIGGER`.

You should have

```
  CREATE TRIGGER remove_my_object_address
    AFTER DELETE ON public.my_objects FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE remove_address()
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
 CREATE TRIGGER remove_user_address
    AFTER DELETE ON public.users FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE remove_address()
            ^^^^^^^^^
```

Source: [The PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: I replaced "EXECUTE TRIGGER" with "EXECUTE PROCEDURE" but got this error when running my migration, "PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE", LINE 11:       CREATE TRIGGER remove_user_address"

Comment: @Dave You need semicolons after each statement.

Comment: @meagar This way to handling function and trigger migration is not executing code on test env migration. Any suggestions?